# Issue with obtaining subscripts in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want both c1 and c2 (see code) in the subscript of the symbol tau. With the following script I am obtaining only c in the subscript. I tried to enclose c1 and c2 with curly braces, but did not work.How to resolve this issue ?

Here is the code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N_combs=10
t1 = np.random.randint(100, size=(N_combs,2))
plt.plot(range(100), np.random.randn(100, N_combs))    
plt.legend([rf'$\tau_c1={x} \tau_c2={y}$' for x,y in t1] ,bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `f` strings or `str.format`, double curly braces are converted to single curly braces and not parsed for evaluation, so you would want this:

```
>>> rf'$\tau_{{c1}}={x} \tau_{{c2}}={y}$'
'$\\tau_{c1}=5 \\tau_{c2}=5$'
```